# How to add custom NARs to a running Docker Nifi without killing container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-nifi

**Environment**

Apache Nifi 1.12.1 running in Docker 18.09.7 on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

**Problem**

How do I add an existing custom NAR to Nifi running in Docker without killing the container.

**Tried**

I have a mount from host to container where I can drop NARs.

*#1 Restart Nifi*

Then I copy the NAR to the `/lib` dir.

Restart Nifi but this kills container

*#2 Copy NAR from mount dir to `/extensions` dir*

As per:
https://www.nifi.rocks/auto-loading-extensions/

But nothing happens

I need to be able to add NARs to Nifi without losing my container

Any help/tips will be much appreciated

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
    nifi:
        build: ./nifi
        container_name: nifi
        ports:
            - 7777:8080
        volumes:
        - ./data:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/data
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM apache/nifi:latest

RUN mkdir /opt/nifi/nifi-current/data
RUN chown -R nifi:nifi /opt/nifi/nifi-current/data

EXPOSE 8080
```

**EDIT**

Looks like copy of NAR into `/extensions` dir is loading the NAR

```
020-10-06 10:35:15,707 INFO [NAR Auto-Loader] org.apache.nifi.nar.StandardNarLoader Starting load process for 1 NARs...
2020-10-06 10:35:15,836 INFO [NAR Auto-Loader] org.apache.nifi.nar.StandardNarLoader Creating class loaders for 1 NARs...
2020-10-06 10:35:15,838 INFO [NAR Auto-Loader] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/./work/nar/extensions/my-nar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[./work/nar/extensions/my-nar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.nar-unpacked]
2020-10-06 10:35:15,838 INFO [NAR Auto-Loader] org.apache.nifi.nar.StandardNarLoader Successfully created class loaders for 1 NARs, 0 were skipped
2020-10-06 10:35:16,076 INFO [NAR Auto-Loader] org.apache.nifi.nar.StandardNarLoader Finished NAR l
```

But it is not showing up in `Add Processor` list ...

**EDIT**

Just needed to refresh Nifi UI in browser to see the processor

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**

*#2 Copy NAR from mount dir to /extensions dir* did the trick.

So I drop NAR into mounted dir, then copy NAR to  `/extensions`

In `nifi-app.log` can see the NAR being loaded

And then  refresh UI and processor can be added to canvas

Comment: Note that you can do this once per custom processor before you have to call docker stop, clear the NAR and put a new one in the mount point.

Comment: Hi Mike, I don't understand what you are saying. I can add 2 NARs to mount and cp them  (one at a time) into extensions dir. No need to stop docker. But maybe I'm missing the point.

Comment: I know that you cannot add same NAR (same name and version) again. As unload from JVM is not supported.

Comment: I was referring to deploying a new copy of a custom NAR.

Answer (score 0):

gary!

I meet this problem as same condition.

This is my solution.

mount another path and use cp XXX.nar /opt/nifi/nifi-current/extensions.

It realy work.

I guest this problem is AUTOLOAD nar use **WatchService** but it can't watch  files are mounted by docker.

**TEST IN Ubuntu**

in Ubuntu,i use this command to run nifi.

`docker run -d -v /root/nifitar:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/extensions -e TZ=Asia/Shanghai  -p 8080:8080 apache/nifi:1.13.2`

and then i copy nars into /root/nifitar in host,nar shows in UI.
so it works, if you are in ubuntu, you can mount dockerdir on host filesystem,and it will work.

Comment: not working is in docker-desktop in my windows 10.